# react-native - Add formula in css StyleSheet will affect performance?

Tags: android, ios, css, user-interface, react-native

I am researching about the responsive in React Native. I add a formula instead of fix digit to css in StyleSheet to make the variable change depend on screen resolution. For example:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 100 * Config.RATIO,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
});
```

The `Config.RATIO` with change depend on the screen resolution. It works. The question are: 
1/ I wonder if it affect the performance of application in the release build? 
2/ If the first question is yes, can you please tell me your solution for react native responsive? I am really appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Consider that you can use `%` as well for responsiveness!

Comment: @M.Khajavi: how about the text size? I am listening for your suggestion :)

Comment: Take a look at [this lib](https://github.com/nirsky/react-native-size-matters) - also you asked about height!

Comment: @M.Khajavi: Thank you for pointing out the issue in my question and let me know the library. Can you make a post so that I can make it the answer to this question? By that way, everyone visits it can find the answer too.

Comment: Of course!  Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that you can use `%` as well for responsiveness.

As you asked about height, take a look at [this library](https://github.com/nirsky/react-native-size-matters).